# How to combine several workbooks with charts using python

Tags: python, excel, merge

I want to merge several workbooks into one keeping the tab record and the graphs and formulae. 
This means:

If there were 2 tabs in the first workbook and 1 tab in the second, the resulting workbook will consist of 3 tabs.

All graphs and formulae are kept as per the original files.

I have tried the solution provided by "Venkata Gogu" in a related post, but it does not save the graphs.
Also, the class openpyxl does not seem to support this either.

Solution by Venkata Gogu:

```
from pandas import ExcelWriter
import glob
import os
import pandas as pd

writer = ExcelWriter("output.xlsx")

for filename in glob.glob("*.xlsx"):
    excel_file = pd.ExcelFile(filename)
    (_, f_name) = os.path.split(filename)
    (f_short_name, _) = os.path.splitext(f_name)
    for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
        df_excel = pd.read_excel(filename, sheet_name=sheet_name)
        df_excel.to_excel(writer, f_short_name+'_'+sheet_name, index=False)

writer.save()
```